# how to fetch private key of metamask account while transaction using web3.js

Tags: web3js, contract-development, transactions, metamask, ethereumjs

I have a problem,
What I want is to user to come at my website, from where he/she can connect to its metamask wallet account, after connecting I want them to allow to do transaction from some specific token address, to admin metamask account, but for transaction we require a private key of a customer's account.

In that case how I will get customer's private key to perform a transaction ? or if there any other way arounf through which I can achieve my requirement, kindly guide me to some solution.

Comment: I would just say, gonon Metamask website and read the doc if you have no idea how blochain works.

Answer (score 2):

Metamask doesn't expose private keys as it's a huge security issue. You shouldn't expect users to expose their private keys either. If you want to sign a transaction or arbitrary data, you can use the Metamask RPC methods. You can find the methods [here](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#unrestricted-methods). With this, you can perform data signing, encryption-decryption with the private keys, in a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

After user connected the metamask wallet, you can send token to admin account without signing the transaction. So you don't need private key of the user. Try this method
web3.eth.sendTransaction